# Windows 10 Black Screen on boot, no cursor, no safe mode, nothing

Tags: windows-10, boot, black-screen-of-death

Last night I was just minding my own business when my monitors kept going black for a few seconds, then turning on again and I noticed that windows was trying to update. Finally it went completely black and I couldn't get it working again so I had to force shut down. Afterwards, windows came back up OK for the night. I noticed while I was using it that it was still trying to install MORE updates. I tried to disable windows update with no success. It was updating and there's nothing I could do to stop it...

This morning I tried to turn it on again, and it's just **completely black**. The fan is loud and the screen is black with **no cursor. No bois screen, no login screen, just black.**

**I can't get to safe mode** ( I tried hitting f5, f8 and f12 )

Note that I was **not** updating from window 8, **I already had windows 10 installed for about a year**

I tried:

- Hard booting over and over
- Unplugging monitor 1 and leaving monitor 2
- Unplugging monitor 2 and leaving monitor 1
- Booting with only monitor 1 plugged in
- Booting with only monitor 2 plugged in
- Pressing f5 during boot
- Pressing f8 during boot
- Pressing f11 during boot
- Pressing f12 during boot
- Unplugging everything and turning it on
- Tried plugging in a different monitor
- Tried creating a windows 10 iso image and made a USB bootable, didn't do anything when i booted it with the USB
- Tried plugging it into my TV
- Tried plugging it in using HDMI, VGA, and a combination of all
- Tried using media creation tool to made a bootable usb, didn't do anything when i booted it with the USB

My specs are:
* NVIDIA GeForce GTX 760
* MSI X79A-GD45 Plus Motherboard

There are hundreds of questions like mine on forums, and I've been reading responses and trying the solutions with NO LUCK! :( Help

UPDATE: I tried booting from USB and didn't see anything either. I looked up my MSI BIOS key and it's F11 and i kept hitting that trying to load but it didn't do anything either. At this point I'm extremely upset... windows update bricked my PC. My display drivers are gone and BIOS doesn't show, USB load doesn't work.. what else am I supposed to do? Wtf windows update

Comment: The update was likely to version 1607, by not allowing it to go ahead and finish, you likely are now in a situation where you will ha e to reinstall Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound dang. Alrighty I'm in the process of downloading windows 10 to a USB and trying to reinstall. thanks

Comment: If there is no [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test) screen then we need to work through troubleshooting on the hardware. First thing's first, do you see a POST screen before it just goes black? If not, is there a beep when you power on?

Comment: If there is no POST I would suggest that your first step should be to clear the CMOS configuration (by shorting the JBAT1 jumper) and switch to BIOS ROM B (slide the Multi-BIOS switch). Detailed instructions on how to do so are in the motherboard manual. I expect this will get you back to a successful POST at which point you can boot from the USB and select *'Repair this Computer'* to try and fix any damage caused to the OS by the failed update.

Comment: "Monitors kept going back for a few seconds" and "no bios screen" sounds like a GPU failure.  Welcome to the club.

Comment: @david25272 That was my first thought too but "the fan is loud" sounds like the pc is not booting to BIOS, since the fan controller isn't kicking in. But I may be wrong... I guess we'll have to wait for the OP.

Comment: A failed GPU can prevent POST from completing and the CPU from loading the BIOS.

Comment: There is no POST screen and no beeps :( K we will clear the CMOS and try it again. Thank you very much for the help @Marvin and david25272